# Gmail automatic login script

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, cakephp-1.3

I have the gmail login credintals.
Is it possible to login automatically to Gmail if we pass the username and password 
through url or by CURL.

Comment: Sounds hardly secure, and I somehow doubt Gmail would accept a username and password in this fashion.  Though I'm sure there is a way.

Comment: Why not use the IMAP interface?

Comment: i dont know how to use that IMAP.. not getting any idea.. can u give any example for IMAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rightclick the gmail login page and view source you can find the id's of the user email and login fields.

You can then use these to write a javascript to fill it automatically and submit.

Theres an implementation here you might check http://techtoggle.com/2009/06/how-to-autologin-into-yahoo-hotmail-lycos-mail/

Edit: its not using the languages you mentioned but its a solution all the same.  Also, while the link url and article title dont mention gmail there is a gmail version of the javascript on the page

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Gmail IMAP interface to access all your mails. [Retrieve Your Gmail Emails Using PHP and IMAP](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap) - details the process with code examples.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already gmail login go to developer login and use google apis

step 1 ) use google client id,

step 2) **g-signin2** this div should call,

finally use below code,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="783587177326-gtl5gpje4riio2ho6qnsfainp4a1mf5o.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}
</script>
```