# Source in browser and file_get_contents give different codes

Tags: php, javascript, gmail

I fetched the http://gmail.com source code from browser and by file_get_contents, both are different.

How can i get same source code which is showing in browser, using php or js or any other programming language (But i preffer php or js)

Comment: I can't imagine any good reason for wanting to do that. Perhaps you should be using the Gmail API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmail.com almost certainly does User Agent sniffing to alter the output according to the browser making the request (despite it being considered bad practice and despite google penalising others for doing it). So my guess is that you're unlikely to get the same source code even between two different browsers, let alone if you fetch it with `file_get_contents`.

You might get somewhere if you use the cURL library instead, and spoof the UA string, but I wouldn't count on even that working completely.

But even if you do that and it works, gmail.com as a site is really heavily dependent on dynamically loaded content; even parts of the script are only loaded when required. I can't see any possible way that loading the gmail site into a PHP script could be remotely useful. And even if you do get it loaded as you want to, what then? They're constantly changing the code, so trying to write a program to parse the HTML code will be an exercise in futility and frustration.

I guess the real question is what are you trying to achieve here? If you want to load your mail from gmail, they provide proper APIs for that kind of thing, which will work much better and more reliably than trying to parse the gmail site itself. I can't think of many other reasons you'd want to do this, so perhaps you should look into the APIs.

The Gmail API for PHP can be downloaded here: http://code.google.com/p/gmail-api/downloads/detail?name=gmail-api.v0.1.php

Comment: I have user name and password for gmail stored in my database, so when user clicks the link he should be automatically logged in to gmail and he will be redirected to gamil(I know it is not seccure, but that is the requirement, i dont have a choice ;().

Comment: Did you search for the answer before posting? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790114/gmail-automatic-login-script (first result in Google for "auto login to gmail via php").

Comment: Also, as you say it's not secure. But also be sure to check; it might be against Gmail's terms of service. If it is, then you're treading on very shaky ground; you might be exposing yourself (or your company) to having your account shut down without warning (or worse) if they don't like you doing this kind of thing.

Comment: I checked the link which you mentioned before posting the question. Answers there doesn't work. Thanks for the answer, I am accepting your answer, as there is no other solution (Almost IMPOSSIBLE)

Answer (score 3):

Try this library [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

and use

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
```

Comment: I was also going to include that in my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Browser shows the generated source code of `google.com` and the php only gets the text written in that index file of google which is Javascript ofcourse!

Comment: what i am actually missing in file_get_contents is some of the javascript code and some of the hidden fields.

Comment: is there any way to get the source code which is same as browser in my php code. i tried CURL, with same browser agent, it gave some more dada than the file_get_contents but not all.